# How to change the resampling method in rasterio's rio.reproject_match function (python)?

Tags: python, raster, python-xarray, gdal, rasterio

I wanted to apply to raster 1 the resolution and origin of raster 2. I found the rasterio's
"rio.reproject_match" function. This take the transformation correctly but I couldn't change the default resampling method (nearst). My raster (1) represents land cover, so I wanted to apply the "mode" method. According to the definition here : https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/html/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.reproject_match

I thought of this code:

```
raster_match = raster_1.rio.reproject_match(raster_2,Resampling = Resampling.mode)
```

But I found the error below:

> NameError: name 'Resampling' is not defined

I wanted to confirm with you if it is possible to change this method directly in rio.reproject_match function and how?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you import it at all? Eg `from rasterio.enums import Resampling`.

Comment: Thank you @ -  Rutger Kassies for your help. Indeed, I only imported rasterio. Once added the module Resampling => it's ok!